# malloc nested variable array of structs?

Tags: c, struct, nested, malloc

How do you go about allocating the data for a struct like below properly (tried adding comments for clarity but been up far too many hours so apologies if they make little to no sense)?

```
struct Cell
{
    int *iData;
    char *cData;
};

struct Row
{
    struct Cell *row;
};

struct Grid
{
    struct Row *grid;
    // Where maxData would be user defined
    // would be the number of elements allocated to member variables of cell
    int maxData;
    // struct Row with rowSize = 3 would be like below?
    // [*Cell][cell][cell][cell]
    int rowSize;
    // columnSize & rowSize = 3 would look something like below?
    //[*Row][*Cell][cell][cell][cell]
    //[*Row][*Cell][cell][cell][cell]
    //[*Row][*Cell][cell][cell][cell]
    int columnSize;
};



//somewhere else in program 
struct Grid *g = malloc(sizeof(struct Grid));
//make user maxData rowSize columnSize assignments here
for(int i = 0; i < g->columnSize; i++)
{
    g->grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Row));
    for(int j = 0; i < g->rowSize; j++)
    {
        g->grid[i]->row[j] = malloc(sizeof(struct Cell));
        g->grid[i]->row[j]->iData = malloc((sizeof(int)) * g->maxData);
        g->grid[i]->row[j]->cData = malloc((sizeof(char)) * g->maxData);
    }
}
```

Is my logic for memory allocation right here?

Was trying something similar in a database program im playing around with but, it segfaults and i cant tell if its my understanding of nested structs like this that is failing or i've just been a bit of a spanner somewhere else in that code.

Many thanks in advance

edit:

The struct that im actually trying to understand how to allocate for is below, just made an example so someone didn't solve my problem for me :) :

```
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
};

struct Database {
    struct Address *rows;
    int maxData;
    int maxRows;
};

struct Connection {
    File *file;
    struct Database *db;
};
```

Comment: regarding: `for(int j = 0; i < g->rowSize; j++)`  the variable `i` is not being modified in the `for()` loop.  I suspect you meant: `for(int j = 0; j < g->rowSize; j++)`

Comment: yeah sorry changed that after i made the post :), was definitely on a lack of sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more useful to use single malloc for whole matrix (if it's possible). To do so you should organize your structure with zero length array as the last member:

```
struct grid {
    int row_count;
    int column_count; 
    int cell_capacity;       
    char data[];
};
```

In that case you can allocate memory once. For example

```
int row_count = 2;
int column_count = 3; 
int cell_capacity = 32;

struct grid* g = calloc(1, sizeof(struct grid)+row_count*column_count*cell_capacity);
 
g->row_count = row_count;
g->column_count = column_count;
g->cell_capacity = cell_capacity;

for(int r = 0; r < row_count; ++r)
  for(int c = 0; c < column_count; ++c)
     strcpy(&g->data[r*column_count*cell_capacity + c*cell_capacity], "hello");
// (*)
free(g);
```

At the (*) point in memory your object will be presented likes the following:

[image]

Comment: Cheers for the reply, decided to stop being lazy and just implement it. I added an edit for the actual struct that i was trying to work out, this one was just an example. My brain definitely stopped functioning about 10hrs ago now so im going to get some sleep and try again later :)

Comment: Had a little play around, realised i just fundamentally dont understand how to use gdb properly so trying to analyse how a struct is stored in memory gets difficult the more complicated they get. Need to do a lot more reading and playing around i think. Thanks for the response though, dont htink i was properly appreciating that when you malloc you just get a pointer and how that section of memory is logically interpreted is completely up to the programmer